Meteor Oauth Token Validation
I'm not very familiar with the Meteor framework, but they have a variety of support for oauth providers, and an ability to plug in custom providers.  I'm wondering if Meteor provides any default token validation (i.e. token signature) for oauth connections, or if that is left up to each provider implementation?
I'm trying to build a custom oauth provider.  In looking at examples in the meteor code, I can see where they are getting tokens, but I don't see any validation of the token before using it.  Maybe I'm missing something?
Examples

Facebook
Google

